# ubuntu server 12.04 and ufw failure on startup, and several module not found errors

Tags: firewall, ufw

I have problem enabling ufw on startup, it works fine if I do:

`sudo ufw enable`. But after restart puf, I've to redo it.

I tried:

```
sudo /lib/ufw/ufw-init stop ; sudo /lib/ufw/ufw-init start
```

And received following errors:

```
WARNING: Deprecated config file /etc/modprobe.conf, all config files belong into /etc/modprobe.d/.
FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ftp not found.
WARNING: Deprecated config file /etc/modprobe.conf, all config files belong into /etc/modprobe.d/.
FATAL: Module nf_nat_ftp not found.
WARNING: Deprecated config file /etc/modprobe.conf, all config files belong into /etc/modprobe.d/.
FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_netbios_ns not found.
iptables-restore: line 69 failed
iptables-restore: line 30 failed
ip6tables-restore: line 65 failed

Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/after.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/before6.rules'
```

In file /etc/ufw/after.rules problem was COMMIT last line, so I went with trial and error and found original culprit:

```
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
```

Uncommented and it was removed from errors.

As for the rest I couldn't go through all of them as they contain allot of rules!

Any ideas how to fix startup problem?

Comment: Are you trying to run ufw in a VPS ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen yes

Comment: Thought so , see - http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/how-to-use-ufw-in-openvz-templates/

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative working solution on OpenVZ (since ufw works from command line but not on init due to `modprobe`, `rsyslog`, `ipv6`, and others) which doesn't require no-oping `modprobe` and other tweaks, one could enable `ufw` via `/etc/rc.local`.

In that case, use `ufw --force enable` to skip the warning prompt for yes/no .

You can also add your rules (e.g. `ufw allow 22`) before the enable command to make sure you're not locked out of your system in case the rules were lost or modified somehow.